# Nautilus cannot browse samba shares in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba, nautilus

I have a problem with browsing samba shares with Nautilus in Ubuntu. I can see work groups but cannot go any deeper.

On the other hand, I can use smbclient and mount samba shares from command line. Also I can browse Ubuntu shares from Windows but not vice versa.

So I suspect it is Nautilus problem. Moreover it has never been working for me since I first started using Ubuntu.

Systems I tried to browse shares on:

- Ubuntu 8-12
- Windows Xp 7
- Dune HD Max

Could someone provide me with ideas how to diagnose this issue? Or describe how network browsing is implemented in Nautilus.

Comment: I have the same issue, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/nautilus-slow-network-or-network-does-not-work/) worked for me: if `smbtree` returns an error instead of a listing of your 
network environment, edit your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and modify the following line:

> ; name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast

which should instead look like this (uncommented and `host` at the end):

> name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host

Apparently you need to reboot after that.